# Cant install Iconify in Angular17

Tags: javascript, angular

I installed:

```
npm install @visurel/iconify-angular
npm i iconify
```

then in shared folder i creatd an icon component and then pasted in icon.component.ts from the docs:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@visurel/iconify-angular

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import home from '@iconify/icons-mdi/home';
import groupAdd from '@iconify/icons-mdi/group-add';
import bellSlash from '@iconify/icons-fa-solid/bell-slash';

@Component({
  selector: 'ic-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  homeIcon = home;
  groupAddIcon = groupAdd;
  bellSlashIcon = bellSlash;
}
```

but i got an error:

```
TS2307: Cannot find module '@iconify/icons-mdi/home' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

How to fix it and install iconify to my angular project?

Comment: I added the import to my angular 17 without any errors https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGDMC.png